# STM32F4 Cube HAL UART. Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Tags: uart, stm32, interrupts, stm32f4

I am using interrupt based UART IO (no DMA).

`HAL_UART_Transmit_IT` function sets `EIE` bit in `CR3` register. According to STM32F407 datasheet (and real behaviour), this generates interrupt only in multi buffer mode (when `DMAR` bit is set). `EIE` enables interrupt generation for frame error (`FE`), overrun error (`ORE`), noise error (`NE`). This error, as I understand, only for receiving.

Part of `HAL_UART_IRQHandler` function:

```
tmp1 = __HAL_UART_GET_FLAG(huart, UART_FLAG_ORE);
tmp2 = __HAL_UART_GET_IT_SOURCE(huart, UART_IT_ERR);
/* UART Over-Run interrupt occurred ----------------------------------------*/
if((tmp1 != RESET) && (tmp2 != RESET))
{ 
  __HAL_UART_CLEAR_OREFLAG(huart);

  huart->ErrorCode |= HAL_UART_ERROR_ORE;
}

if(huart->ErrorCode != HAL_UART_ERROR_NONE)
{
  /* Set the UART state ready to be able to start again the process */
  huart->State = HAL_UART_STATE_READY;

  HAL_UART_ErrorCallback(huart);
}
```

`HAL_UART_IRQHandler` checks for each error. If error occurred and `EIE` bit is set, it resets UART state, but doesn't reset interrupt enabling bits, so `TXE` interrupt will be always generated, but `UART_Transmit_IT` function treats state `HAL_UART_STATE_READY` as invalid and doesn't do anything. Infinite loop.

Part of `UART_Transmit_IT` function:

```
static HAL_StatusTypeDef UART_Transmit_IT(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
  {
  uint16_t* tmp;
  uint32_t tmp1 = 0;

  tmp1 = huart->State;
  if((tmp1 == HAL_UART_STATE_BUSY_TX) || (tmp1 == HAL_UART_STATE_BUSY_TX_RX))
  {
  }
  else
  {
    return HAL_BUSY;
  }
}
```

Is it a bug in Cube HAL?

Comment: three and a half years later and this is still a problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bug.

I asked same question on the ST forum: https://my.st.com/d5c15f59

They confirmed it.

Comment: The "my.st.com" link requires a login. I found [this thread](https://my.st.com/public/STe2ecommunities/mcu/Lists/STM32Java/Flat.aspx?RootFolder=https%3a%2f%2fmy%2est%2ecom%2fpublic%2fSTe2ecommunities%2fmcu%2fLists%2fSTM32Java%2fSTM32F4%20Cube%20HAL%20UART%2e%20Is%20it%20a%20bug%20or%20am%20I%20missing%20something&FolderCTID=0x01200200770978C69A1141439FE559EB459D758000F9A0E3A95BA69146A17C2E80209ADC21) on the ST forum, which I think is the reporting of this problem, and is accessible without a login, so readers may find that useful.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to download the lastest version of Cube HAL for your MCU?

My HAL_UART_Transmit_IT() function seems very different than yours. Maybe you have an older version with bugs.

Try access st.com and search for the lastest version of Cube HAL. Inside the archive you'll find some example with USART.

Comment: `HAL_UART_Transmit_IT` and `UART_Transmit_IT` are different functions. First only sets up interrupts, while second actually transmits data

Comment: Yes, but you know that second function can only be call by other HAL function not direct by user? And i just open my HAL source files and find UART_Transmit_IT and its different than the part you paste above. Other option if you still think there is a bug is to write the same question on st forum.